# Get Executable Binary for a Single C Function

Tags: c, build

I have a simple C function, called `add`:

```c
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I need to get the optimized executable binary code for this given function without any of the other side effects of the binary.  This would then be dynamically loaded and modified to include templates via a JIT system.  I have experimented with trying to use objdump, but that doesn't really work for getting the actual binary as the object file is not the actual executable.

I need to link together the moving parts of functions to include their binary together at runtime and enabled PROT_EXEC to execute all of these partials together as a single function and call as a function pointer.  The reason I need this is because I have a byte instruction encoding type which I would like to turn into JIT functions on the fly (similar to JIT compiling RegExp into validator functions).  If there are any other viable solutions I should consider, then please describe them.

The main reason I want to use this approach is because I can see the godbolt shows the binary for functions as self-contained, so hopefully I can do something similar to include the binary in my own project.

Thank you for any help.

Note: the C function is entirely self-contained without referencing other functions

Comment: You probably want a shared library.  Are you building for Linux or Windows?

Comment: Compile to actual executable, then objdump?

Comment: @MikeCAT I've tried that, but it's hard to programmatically use objdump for this.

Comment: @dbush I see the assembly when I generate it as a shared library, although I'm seeing it's not working to compile it to binary.

Comment: An executable will have a `main()` function — it won't contain only a single function.  If you create a shared library with a single object file containing a single function, then you could dynamically load the shared library and gain access to that function.  It doesn't sound particularly sensible, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem is that I need to append parts of this function then include other "partials" from other function binaries together at runtime.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Please update your question to include more details on what you're actually trying to accomplish, preferably with an example.

Comment: It'll be fun rewriting the assembly/object code management facilities so that you can 'append' — and you'll still need to write a shared library to be able to use it.  Think about whether an embedded scripting language is more suitable than raw C.  Think about whether what you're doing is sensible; it doesn't sound like it.  The scenario isn't clear.  It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @dbush I have updated my question, hopefully it seems clearer now.

Comment: I think I might be better off just copying the assembly parts into my JIT builder because then I can dynamically set the registers for each part.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Executable files" need not have `main()` function. (they may not actually be executable though) https://wandbox.org/permlink/aA72Rm1YT1s9g3RG

Comment: hmm actually I'll just copy the code from Dora VM to work for me

Comment: Perhaps this has been suggested and rejected, but: the easiest solution ought to be to compile to an `.so` file, then use `dlopen` to load it at runtime, and `dlsym` to find symbols in it to call & use.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using `IDA`. You can compile your code (preferably with symbols) into ELF file/ EXE file and open the generated file in IDA.
There you can see your function in the function window and then move into the hex window to copy the hex dump of your function.

**Note:** There are a lot of things that can go wrong here, for example, you must compile your code with the flag `-PIC` so it wouldn't use absolute addresses.

It is also recommended to know at least basic assembly.

This link might be interesting: https://github.com/Neetx/Shellcode-Extractor